# How to fix JSX props error in Vue template?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, fullcalendar, eslint, vite

Since I added the FullCalendar library to my Vue project, I have encountered this error whenever I use my custom component in a vue template.

I'm using Vue 3, Vite, VSCode, eslint and prettier.

It seems like this problem is more likely to happen to ReactJS, and I didn't find any solution for Vue.

Please help me.

[image: JSX error vue template]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @KibéM.C I don't want my VSCode to show that error, because I'm using vue template and I don't understand why JSX error is showing here. Before I add FullCalendar library everything was perfectly fine. I didn't get any JSX error whatsoever.

Comment: Share your function code

Comment: @KibéM.C I don't even have a function. That error just appears where I use a Vue Component, even if that's a Hello world component with only HTML and no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with jsx.d.ts file from prect package, it seems to be a dependency for @fullcalender. Apparently VSCode uses the types from this file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. So how can I fix it?